# Why will my basic calculator not process after String input

Tags: java

This program is supposed to be a basic calculator that takes two double inputs and then prompts for the user to type a string with a corresponding mathematical operator. For some reason my basic calculator will not return a value after the user has input a String corresponding to the menu.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;  
    public class Assignment3 {  
        public static void main (String[] args)  
     {
        String operator = "";
        double userInputOne;
        double userInputTwo;
        double output = -.00001;
        String comparison = "";


         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("Enter the first number of your calculation:");
         userInputOne = scan.nextDouble();

         System.out.println("Enter the second number of your calculation:");
         userInputTwo = scan.nextDouble();

          System.out.println("Type in one direction under Calculator Options:");
          System.out.println("Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide, Mod");
          System.out.println("Compare");
          System.out.println("Print Numbers");
          System.out.println("Quit");
          Scanner scanTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
          operator = scanTwo.nextLine();

        if (operator == "Add")
        {
            output = userInputOne + userInputTwo;
        }else if (operator == "Subtract"){
            output = userInputOne - userInputTwo;
        }else if (operator == "Multiply"){
            output = userInputOne * userInputTwo;
        }else if (operator == "Divide"){
            output = userInputOne / userInputTwo;
        }else if (operator == "Mod"){
            output = userInputOne % userInputTwo;
        }else if (operator == "Compare"){
            if(userInputOne == userInputTwo){
                comparison = (userInputOne + " Is equal to " +      userInputTwo);
                System.out.println(comparison);
            }else if (userInputOne > userInputTwo){
                comparison = (userInputOne + " Is greater than " + userInputTwo);
                System.out.println(comparison);
            }else if (userInputOne < userInputTwo){
                comparison = (userInputOne + " Is less than " + userInputTwo);
                System.out.println(comparison);
            }
        }else if (operator == "Print Numbers"){
            comparison = userInputOne + "  " + userInputTwo;
            System.out.println(comparison);
        }else if (operator == "Quit"){
            System.exit(0);
        }


        if (output != -.00001){
        System.out.println(output);
        }

}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compare strings with `==` you need to use `operator.equals()`

For example instead of `operator == "Subtract"` use `"Subtract".equals(operator)`

Comment: Thank you! Also how can I make it so my code will loop unless someone actually inputs the "Quit" string?

Comment: `while(!"Quit".equals(operator))`?

Comment: @user2341539 - use a `do-while` or may be a `while` loop, depending on your needs. `while(!"Quit".equals(operator))`

Comment: for some reason it keeps executing whichever function I pick indefinitely. Can someone help?

Comment: Are you updating operator within the loop?

Comment: Yes the operator is updated in the loop. Sorry about that, I didn't know about accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

For String value comparisons, you need to use the [`String#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

`==` is used for object reference comparisons.

Hence, all your `operator` comparisons need to be like this:-

```
if ("Add".equals(operator))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of the `==` for comparing Strings. Which Java version are you using? As stated by others, you can use `equals()` instead, but as of of Java 7, you can use `switch` for String comparison:

```
switch (operator) {

    case "Add":
        utput = userInputOne + userInputTwo;
        break;

    case "Subtract":
        utput = userInputOne - userInputTwo;
        break;

    case "Multiply":
        utput = userInputOne * userInputTwo;
        break;

    // ...

    default:
       // optional default statement
       break;
}
```

Note the `break` statement at the end of each `case` to prevent fall through.

More information is available in the Oracle's [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) (scroll down to "Using Strings in switch Statements").