# Problems with ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> and IF-STATEMENT

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have a Array List with HashMap

```
deviceDataCollection = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

I have to retrieve some data from this Array e compare using an IF-STATMENT, like the code below:

```
String DeviceType = deviceDataCollection.get(position).get("var").toString();
//it returns a string: lamp 

if (DeviceType == "lamp")
{
       // do something
}
```

The problem is: I can't get enter the IF-STATEMENT. I'm sure the values are exact the same.

I don't know what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Refer to my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16329952/2024761) here! `if ("lamp".equals(DeviceType))` is what you need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use equals("lamp") or equalsIgnoreCase("lamp") method to co0mpare two Strings.

```
if (DeviceType .equals("lamp"))
 {
   // do something
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. It has worked perfectly.

Comment: @user2341575 did you just vote and unvote?

Answer (score 0):

When comparing Strings use equals()

So in your conditional it should be `DeviceType.equals("lamp")`

Answer (score 0):

When you compare reference types in Java (and Android) you need to use the `.equals()` method:

```
if (DeviceType.equals("lamp"))
{
       // do something
}
```

`==` determines equality by when something is in memory, `.equals()` will consider its value.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    if ("lamp".equals(DeviceType))
    {
             //do something
    }
```

The operator, ==, tests to see if two object reference variables refer to the exact same instance of an object.

The method, .equals(), tests to see if the two objects being compared to each other are equivalent -- but they need not be the exact same instance of the same object.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Check the equals method in the link above

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (DeviceType.equals("lamp"))
{
   // do something
}
```

Strings are compared using `equals` function and not ==.